# Should I normalize returns when performing a paired t test?

Tags: t-test, paired-data, finance

I am trying to see what trading strategy is better with back testing. The data is The daily FX  rates from the last 20 years. However, each of the 2 strategies generates different entry/exit signals, hence resulting in different holding period.

My question is: when performing a paired t test on te series of returns, should I first put all the returns in daily return before performing the t test? Or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You have daily data and you can stick to that. Say that your out-of-sample test period is $T$ days. Regardless of entry/exit and holding periods, you have $T$ daily returns for each strategy, $\{x_t\}_{t=1}^T$ and $\{y_t\}_{t=1}^T$. Take their difference $\{z_t\}_{t=1}^T := \{y_t-x_t\}_{t=1}^T$, model them (as i.i.d., as ARMA-GARCH or in some other way) and test whether the mean of the $z$ series is equal to zero. If you assume i.i.d.'ness, Student's $t$-test will do the job. If you assume ARMA-GARCH, look at the significance of the intercept of the ARMA model.